# How remove metaclasses info when writing to yaml?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, netplan, python-netifaces

```
import netifaces
import netaddr
import yaml


class Ethernet(yaml.YAMLObject):
    def __init__(self, addresses, gateway4, mtu, nameservers):
        self.nameservers = nameservers
        self.mtu = mtu
        self.gateway4 = gateway4
        self.addresses = addresses
```

I am trying to write this class to a yum file:

```
with open("/home/netplan.yaml", "w") as file:
    yaml.dump(document, file, default_flow_style=False)
```

I get this result:

```
!!python/object:__main__.Netplan
network: !!python/object:__main__.Network
  ethernets:
    docker0: !!python/object:__main__.Ethernet
      addresses:
      - 172.26.0.1/16
      gateway4: 1.1.1.1
      mtu: 9000
```

How is it possible to remove all meta information like
**!!python/object:**main**.**
from a yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what a *yum* is but I will assume that you're talking about YAML.

You can define a class attribute `yaml_tag` to control the tag used when serializing your class. If you set it to the default tag for mappings, it won't be written:

```py
from yaml.resolver import BaseResolver

class Ethernet(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = BaseResolver.DEFAULT_MAPPING_TAG

    def __init__(self, addresses, gateway4, mtu, nameservers):
        self.nameservers = nameservers
        self.mtu = mtu
        self.gateway4 = gateway4
        self.addresses = addresses
```

However note that if you do this, you can't load the YAML into this class again.

If you don't have control over the types you dump, you can register a custom representer for them instead:

```py
yaml.add_representer(Foo, lambda dumper, data: dumper.represent_mapping(
    BaseResolver.DEFAULT_MAPPING_TAG, data.__dict__))
```

Comment: It's a misprint! Thank you!